# Populate multiple g:select with an array variable

Tags: html, grails

I am trying to have two multiple select lists that I am trying to do the typical add/remove between the two. I am able to add and remove initially and save the array of values from the second g:select but I cannot seem to repopulate the second g:select when I try to show the user an updated value.

```
<table class="threecols">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 10%">
     <g:select multiple="true" id="select1" name="select1" from="${['User','Department','School','Class','User','Id','District']}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%">
        <button type="button" style="margin-left: 12px"><a href="#" id="add">Add &gt;&gt;</a>
        </button>
        <button type="button"><a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt; Remove</a>    </button>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 10%">
     <g:select multiple="true" id="select2" name="paramList" from="${report?.paramList}" value="${report?.paramList}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the variable declaration is: String[] paramList
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JQuery to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#select2 option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select1').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        $('#select1 option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select2').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

});
```

More Info here: [Link](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/create-add-remove-select-lists-using-jquery/)

Comment: I have the add remove section working its more of the on page load how do I load my string array as values for the second select but thank you! I reread my question and I kinda butchered that question.

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid and was using report?.paramList when I should have used reportInstance?.paramList since report is just the class where reportInstance was a singular object. Woops.